# ASP.Net Core 2.0 Identity uses Cookies, even if configured otherwise

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core

I'm currently implementing an example of using JWT with the identity mechanism of ASP.Net Core 2.0.
According to the GitHub example here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310, I'm configuring the service like this:

```
    private void InitializeJwtAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var securityKey = _securityKeyFactory.CreateSecurityKey();

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(
            options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }
        ).AddJwtBearer(
            options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            });
    }
```

And the middleware simply with:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I'm also overriding the Stores in order to have an own implementation in order to provide user data. In order to log in, I'm using the SignIn manager:

```
    public async Task<SignInResultDto> SignInAsync(AuthenticationRequestDto authenticationRequestDto)
    {
        var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(authenticationRequestDto.UserName, authenticationRequestDto.Password, true, false);
        var serializedJwtToken = string.Empty;

        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            serializedJwtToken = await _jwtTokenAppFactory.CreateSerializedJtwTokenAsync(authenticationRequestDto.UserName);
        }

        var result = new SignInResultDto
        {
            SerializedJwtToken = serializedJwtToken,
            Succeeded = signInResult.Succeeded
        };

        return result;
    }
```

And the JWT token factory using a simple implementation:

```
    public async Task<string> CreateSerializedJtwTokenAsync(string userName)
    {
        var secretKey = _securityKeyFactory.CreateSecurityKey();
        var appUser = _appUserFactory.Create(userName);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("tEST", "tra")
        };

        var jwtHeader = new JwtHeader(new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
        var jwtPayload = new JwtPayload(claims);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtHeader, jwtPayload);

        var result = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        return result;
    }
```

Everything seems to work fine, but interesting enough, if I use postman to log in and check the data, it is receiving a Cookie. Furthermore, if I delete the Cookie and just pass the bearer token, the authentication doesn't work anymore. The general login seems to work, since I can see the custom Claim, if I'm debugging, but the JWT mechanism seems to get ignored.

Am I missing here something?